# Do all Debian packages work on Debian 10?

Tags: linux, debian, package-management, distributions

I was looking for a Linux distribution for desktop and pen-testing usage (without VM), so I wanted to know that can I install any of the packages of Kali-Linux/Black-Arch separately on its main distro (Debian)?

Comment: This question has no meaning. Debian has 3 main pools, sid/unstable, testing, stable, plus old stable and experimental. It's a question of dependencies for the specific pool in question, and in your case, kali would be another pool. There is no possible answer to your question because it's too broad. You could easily make a package with a dependency only kali has which would then not be installable on testing.

Comment: open-source *nix and commercial *nix have the same issue: fragmentation. packages designed for one OS (distribution) have no guarantee of working unmodified on another _even if one is derived from the other_. one advantage of open-source is that the code is available for you to create your own package when your vendor (distro's repository) doesn't provide it

Comment: It's unclear whether you talk about applications or about packages. The email reader `mutt` works on both Debian and Kali (and any other Linux or Unix), but the Kali _package_ for `mutt` may not work on Debian.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is no, there are packages which do not work on the “main” distro.  There are clearly packages that work on Ubuntu but do not on Debian, either because they depend on a newer version of a package, on a dependency that Debian does not have, or simply are incompatible.  For example, if one distro decides to version the symbols in a shared library but the other does not, the dependencies will fail to work.  I've literally seen cases where a package from Ubuntu I thought was perfectly compatible with Debian was not and broke things in a subtle way.

It is often possible to use a package from, say, Ubuntu on Debian or vice versa, but it is not guaranteed to work, and if you have problems, the maintainers for your distro will probably not be very interested in fixing it.  So if you decide to do this, you're on your own.

Comment: Do you know an app that runs on Kali Linux but not on Debian 10?

Comment: I don't, because I don't use Kali.

Comment: @Daniel Do you by "app" mean a particular application or a specific package containing that application? Are you talking about software in general, or about packages containing software, packaged for a particular Linux?